# How to use mongoDB 4.2 in HELM deployment?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes-helm

I want to use mongoDB4.2 in my application. But when I am deploying MongoDB using helm i.e. stable/mongodb it is installing MongoDB 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem in stable/mongodb is that it uses 4.0 version image. You need to change it to 4.2.

change tag **4.0.13-debian-9-r22** in values.yaml file in line 21 to **4.2** . It will work .